# JPA Spring Query sql

Tags: java, sql

I have a query in `sql`.  I want to write it in JPA Spring.

How can i do it ?

`SELECT * FROM user WHERE user.id=3 and user.enabled=1`

Comment: there is already mistake in sql query = )

Comment: Do you want a jpql query or do you want to execute the sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform a native SQL query in JPA you have to do the following:

```
EntityManager manager = getEntityManager(); 
Query query = manager.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user.id = :id AND user.enabled = :enabled;");
query.setParameter("id", 3);
query.setParameter("enabled", 1);
Object[] user = query.getSingleResult();
```

If you want a JPQL query:

```
EntityManager manager = getEntityManager();
TypedQuery<User> query = manager.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.id = :id AND user.enabled = :enabled;", User.class);
query.setParameter("id", 3);
query.setParameter("enabled", 1);
User user = query.getSingleResult();
```

Using the JPQL query is the better style because it is type-safe. You can perform the statement directly on the entity without knowing the specific table structure of your database.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please mark the anwere as correct. So your question will be displayed as anwered.